# How to rid latest Eclipse (2021-03) of MANIFEST.MF (No such file or directory) error?

Tags: eclipse, maven, manifest.mf

Over the last few years, for our Parent POM project in Eclipse, I've had to employ slightly different tweaks to Eclipse's configuration, to avoid having Eclipse give errors like:

```
...target/classes/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF (No such file or directory)  pom.xml
```

I know I can manually rid these errors, by right-clicking the parent project and doing

```
Maven > Update Project
```

but that only works until the next build when I do another "clean install".

In the past, I got Eclipse to stop complaining by making these 2 Eclipse tweaks:

```
Preferences > Maven > check "Automatically update Maven projects configuration (experimental)"
Preferences > Maven > Java EE Integration > uncheck "Maven Archiver generates files under the build directory".
```

But, this no longer work, with the latest versions of Eclipse (e.g., Version: 2021-03).

Why does Eclipse do this and how can I rid myself of this annoyance, once and for all?

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I never had such errors in any version of Ecilpse. Have you tried to figure out the reason behind the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution.

The problem is caused by the standard maven-compiler-plugin. When it generates a JAR file, it deletes target/classes/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF.
Eventually (but not right away), Eclipse notices this and complains that the manifest file is missing.

Cleaning the project (as often recommended in related Stack Overflow questions) is not a solution. Although it makes the errors go away temporarily, the errors will soon return, the next time maven-compiler-plugin generates another JAR file.

A permanent solution is to include this additional plugin to my POM, which not just generates a manifest file, but KEEPS it at target/classes/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF:

```
...
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>bundle-manifest</id>
                    <phase>compile</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>manifest</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <index>true</index>
                    <manifest>
                        <addDefaultSpecificationEntries>false</addDefaultSpecificationEntries>
                        <addDefaultImplementationEntries>false</addDefaultImplementationEntries>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            ...
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            ...
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            ...
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
    ...
</build>
...
```